# OAuth callback URI changes port number in Azure emulator

Tags: azure, oauth

I've developed a working solution using Azure SDK October 2012. It connects to another service that uses OAuth. When I move my solution to a machine using Azure SDK 2.1, the OAuth callback fails because the port number has changed.

For example, when I debug the solution it opens a browser at 127.0.0.2:82. Then I connect to the other service, and the callback comes to 127.0.0.2:83, which the browser can't find. Prior to being redirected to the other service, I can see that the controller is looking at the Request object and getting the invalid port # (83) from that.

I'm not a MVC or Azure whiz, but this solution works perfectly under the older version of the SDK. Did something change? btw I've tested this with IE10 and Chrome, so it's not a browser issue.

Just to be clear - I have the exact same solution running on 2 machines. One works, and the other doesn't. So it's not a problem with my code, unless there's something that explicitly needs to change for Azure SDK after October 2012.

Comment: I just wanted to add that I did publish this to Azure staging (from the dev machine that has the problem) and it works there. So it's definitely something to do with local settings or version of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The Oauth2 app has been configured to redirect on specific site + port, so either you need to reconfigure the Oauth2 configuration in the OAuthProvider

or else see why the emulator locally is binding to a different port. Maybe the other port is being used by some other site running in the emulator. Sometimes just restarting the emulator does the trick.

See [this](http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/05/windows-azure-basicscompute-emulator.html) to understand how the local emulator works.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the [Authorize] attribute on the controller method that was looking at the Request object. When I added that, the port number problem went away.

Still not sure why it worked on one dev machine and not the other (or with one version of Azure SDK and not the other), but now it works on both, so there you have it.